# ReactNative TouchableOpacity makes view dissapear?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Consider the following example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import snackicon from './assets/snack-icon.png';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
    {/*<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("View clicked")}>*/}
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#00000050', marginRight: 5, borderRadius: 15}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Image style={{alignSelf: 'stretch', flex: 1, resizeMode: 'contain', width: 'auto' }} source={snackicon}></Image>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 3}}>
        </View>
    </View>
    {/*</TouchableOpacity>*/}
    <View style={{flex: 10, flexDirection: 'column'}}></View>
    </>
  );
}
```

This shows a view with an Image in it; However if you uncomment the TouchableOpacity the entire view disappears. What exactly is causing this?

Expo link if anyone wants to try live: https://snack.expo.io/qt_gAkTaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `flex: 1` to define the height of your nested `View` component. Since it has a `flex: 1` and your other `View` has `flex: 10`, it takes 1/10 of the screen.

Your `TouchableOpacity` doesn't have a `height` nor `flex` property, so it doesn't grow.

I suggest trying to put `flex: 1` in the styles of `TouchableOpacity`.